# "Data-loading" button not getting disabled in twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I'm working on twitter bootstrap "data-loading" button.Below posted is my code.The button has to get disabled once it exceeds the page-limit.I was able to do it with normal button that doesnot contain "data-loading" option.Below posted is my code

```
 <head>

  <style type="text/css">
   * {
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     }
 </style>  
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

  var track_click =0;

  var y = <?php echo $y; ?>;

    $('#ram').load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':track_click}, function(){track_click++;   
     });
    $('.load_more').on("click",function()
    { 


    if(track_click<=y)
    {
        $.post('fetch_pages.php',{'page': track_click},function(data){
            $('.load_more').show();
            $('#ram').append(data);
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#hi").offset().top}, 500);


            track_click++;
        }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
            alert(thrownError); //alert any HTTP error
            $(".load_more").show(); //bring back load more button
        });

    if(track_click >= y-1)
    {
            $('.load_more').attr('disabled','disabled');


    }
    }


    });
    });

  $(function() { 
      $(".btn").click(function(){
      var btn = $(this)
      btn.button('loading')
      setTimeout(function(){
      btn.button('reset')},100);


      });        
     });




   </script>
 </head>
<?php

 include 'config.inc.php';
 $query = "select count(*) from posts";
 $exec = mysqli_query($connecDB,$query);
 $ref = mysqli_fetch_array($exec);
 echo $item_per_page;
 $y=$ref[0];
 $k=ceil($y/$item_per_page);

      ?>




   <body>
    <div align="center">
     <button class="  load_more btn btn-primary" name = "test"  id="hi">load       

      More</button>

       </div>
    <div id = "ram">

    </div>



 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr`:

```
$('.load_more').prop('disabled',true);
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, you need to check what's in `track_click` and `y`, which we can't really do for you without some sort of actual data.

EDIT:
[I put your code in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/buyeveji/1/) and it seems to run fine with hard coded variables and without the post, so I think it's something wrong with some other part of your code.

Comment: actually i have reedited the code a bit..Earlier y used to have number of items,now it consists of number of pages..  so in my case... i have  18 items..and items that are supposed to be displayed on a page are 3,which means i have six pages for me..in y "y=6"..  track_click also has the same value

Comment: So what would `y` be when the page loads? 6?

Comment: the page-loading button should get disabled,Instead it is still showing "loading"

Comment: Looking more closely at your code, I'm very confused. There are random `script` and `link` tags all over, you have `head`, `style` and `script` tags outside of your `html` tag, and some formatting issues. Could you refactor your posted code to make it more organized?

Comment: See my edit. I don't think the problem is the part of the code you think it is.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qicajeli/1/edit  Here is what i'm trying to explain you .As soon as it exceeds the value of y ,The data loading button should get disabled.instead it is still active..You can find this thing in the above url

Comment: If you look at my example, that's exactly what's happening. When `track_click` becomes greater than `y-1` the button is disabled. I just hardcoded `y = 6` and took out the `$.load(...)` because I can't test those without your code.